# Manage null values of xmlagg

Tags: xml, oracle, scala, apache-spark, aggregation

I have a query of the following structure:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || col_list || ' from schema.table;' from( Select table_name,  rtrim(xmlagg(xml element(e,  Case when datatype in ('blob', 'timestamp') then null else column_name end , ', ').extract('//text()') order by c_id).getclobval(), ', ' ) col_list from all_tab_cols where schema ='schema' and table in ('t1', 't2') group by table_name)
```

This gives me output when the first two, fourth and sixth columns are of the blob or timestamp type is :

```
SELECT ,  ,  third_col, , fifth_col, from schema.table;
```

How to modify the query so it provides :

```
SELECT third_col,  fifth_col from schema.table;
```

This resulting select statement is further stored as a row in a spark dataframe (I'm using Scala) . So, if we can modify the query through regex or replacing substrings, that can also work out and I'm open to those suggestions too but I'd appreciate if I don't have to go about hacking that way into it and manage it on the query side itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinking you're over-complicating this; just don't include those columns at all, by filtering them out in the `where` clause:

```
...
  from all_tab_cols
  where owner = 'schema'
  and table_name in ('t1', 't2')
  and data_type != 'BLOB'
  and data_type not like 'TIMESTAMP%'
  group by table_name
)
```

You can then remove the case expression.

You can also simplify it a bit:

```
select 'SELECT '
  || rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, column_name, ', ').extract('//text()') order by column_id).getclobval(), ', ' )
  || ' FROM ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ';'
from all_tab_cols
where owner = 'schema'
and table_name in ('t1', 't2')
and data_type != 'BLOB'
and data_type not like 'TIMESTAMP%'
group by owner, table_name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=30675b1c8a5a30377adadefc727719b1)

Comment: I cannot use listagg because the aggregated column list exceeds 4000bytes, secondly I cannot use where clause because along with the list I'm getting table names. I've just provided in the nested select the aggregated column list, but there are multiple tables and each table we will generate its concatenated list. So, if we use where clause it will exclude that entire aggregated list of columns for that table and not just exclude those particular columns of the blob and timestamp type.

Comment: Let me update the query of what it actually looks like. With listagg when we use case and if it is null, the aggregated column just ignores it but that isn't the case with xmlagg. That's why I'm lookin for the best way to handle it so only particular column types gets excluded from the select statement.

Comment: I don't understand your second point. It only excludes the columns with those types, not any other columns for that table, or the whole table.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the first. updated query. It's trying to fetch, table names and their respective concatenated column names in the nested select. So say, if t1 has three columns of varchar, number and blob type, the nested query should return t1 with the col_list as c1, c2. If you put a where clause saying datatype not in('blob') it won't return that table_name and col_list at all. If I'm getting anything wrong, can you please write an example query and demonstrate.

Comment: You're right. It works, my bad. I presumed that if I try to use not in inside the where clause it will exclude the entire tables which have the columns of the excluded type. Thank you

Comment: OK, good. `IN` doesn't really work with timestamps as they have sizes as part of the datatype itself, so I modified that slightly. I've also added a simplified query, and a demo.